# Voting on posts with a bad internet connection results in confusion

Tags: support, voting

When you open a page, read the question and/or answers, it's not uncommon for your internet connection to fail without you knowing *(until you try to send a request by clicking on a link, etc)*.

Let's say it's one of those bad internet connection days; you vote on a post, and a *courteous light pink* banner appears on the top of the screen *(probably to not block the user's view)* displaying the words:

*An error has occurred - please retry your request.*

This is after pressing the arrow; the banner won't appear until you move the cursor:

[image]

This is after pressing the arrow and moving the courser:

[image]

Not too hard to notice, but also not too hard to overlook. Still, the message is not very clear that it means that your vote didn't cast. Plus, the banner disappears within in a matter of seconds, so perhaps you've looked away for just a couple of seconds and didn't catch it.

The problem is, the vote count will *appear* to have increased/decreased *(depending on whether you've attempted to upvote or downvote)*
in the browser, and the selected arrow will be highlighted.

If your internet connection gets fixed before you leave that page,
as you continue to interact with the page, like editing, answering, commenting, etc., the inaccurate vote count will remain

This may have resulted in plenty of cast votes that weren't cast.
When you attempt to vote on a comment when you're offline, a **deep red** message pops **right above the cursor** that says:

*An error occurred during voting*

This is pressing the arrow:

[image]

This is after moving the cursor:

[image]

The message there is strong and clear, the vote count doesn't change and the arrow won't be highlighted.

**Couldn't the offline voting behavior on posts act more like the offline voting behavior of comments, being more straightforward to notify the user of the issue before they click away to other posts?**

It may seem rare for your internet connection to fail mid-reading a page, but it does happen, and even more when the weather is bad, using a cable, or simply have poor internet connections. If the voting on comments system works fine, why shouldn't the voting on posts be like that as well?

Comment: A somewhat similar issue I'm using [a userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Websocket-Indicator) for is a visual indicator of whether the websocket to Stack Exchange is open or not. When it's red, I know that the internet's down, or a proxy is failing, or something similar, and I don't try to make requests (like voting). The websocket isn't 100% tied to the status of the current connection, but it's usually close.

Answer (score 9):

This "bug report" is asking for a rewrite of the (front-end) voting logic for the corner case where a user loses connection *after* successfully loading the whole page. That seems excessively rare.

You could just reload the page if you see that error message appear...

Comment: Maybe the underlaying logic is significantly different, who knows...

Comment: @AnnZen this happens to me as well. but its not very common. if your internet randomly dies, then fix it.

Comment: @10Rep fix the root cause, not the symptoms. Always good advice.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for your advice! But I'm sure not everyone is fortunate enough to be *able* to have good internet access.

Comment: @AnnZen Sorry, but how is that Stackoverflows problem? Bad internet isn’t something we can fix. If my computer is broken, and I can’t visit the main site, then will I raise a post here saying SO should fix that?

Comment: @10Rep Well let me ask you this. Let me just ask you this. I just want to ask you [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNaHRxFwiKo)... Why doesn't the voting on comments system have the same issue?

Comment: @AnnZen Comment voting is different. For one, you can't downvote comments. And you'd have to ask an SE dev about the underlaying logic. And as Gimby said, fix your internet. If you cannot, then I am sorry. It's not our fault.

Comment: @10Rep I've never said it's anybody's fault. I'm just bringing up the issue for future readers who encounter such a problem. Mind you that I am part of that "our". It appears to me that you are trying to make it seem like I'm against the community, please stop.

Comment: @AnnZen When I say "our", that just means SE. Also, it seems as though you are accusing me, to be entirely honest. I'm just conveying what I've learnt.